# What exactly is scalaz's Signal for?

Tags: scala, scalaz

[`scalaz.stream.async.immutable.Signal`](https://github.com/krasserm/scalaz-stream/blob/master/src/main/scala/scalaz/stream/async/immutable/Signal.scala) provides the following methods:

```
def changed: Process[Task, Boolean]
def discrete: Process[Task, A]
def continuous: Process[Task, A]
def changes: Process[Task, Unit]
```

Conspicuously missing are operations like `map`, `flatMap`  and `zip`. Also, there seems to be no way (other than `.continuous.once.run.run`) to get the "current" value of a signal.

Are Scalaz signals actually meant to model a value that changes over time in a similar way to [`reactive.Signal`](https://github.com/nafg/reactive/tree/v0.4.0/reactive-core)? Or is it something else entirely?